# change collection optional value in swift?

Tags: swift, collections, optional-values

`rowDescriptor` is a `AnyObject?` type, I get convert `self.rowDescriptor?.value` to `images`. I want to add image to the `self.rowDescriptor?.value`. I failed to do it as below. `images` has one  value. but `self.rowDescriptor?.value` still empty. I can't find any document about it. what's the reason about it.

```
    var images :[UIImage] = self.rowDescriptor?.value as! [UIImage]
    if let image = editedImage {
        images.append(image)
    } else {
        images.append(originalImage!)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array type in Swift is a struct. Structs in swift are value types not reference types. To clarify:

`images` contains a copy of `self.rowDescriptor?.value`

`images.append(` changes the copy `images`, not the original value in your `rowDescriptor.value`

You want to change `self.rowDescriptor?.value` so just set that to your newly changed `image`s array.

```
self.rowDescriptor?.value = images
```

## td;dr

To fix, add `self.rowDescriptor?.value = images`.